# unable to mount device

Tags: filesystems, mount, automounting

Im trying to use two atapi devices at the same type one EIDE and one SATA, reported by

```
dmesg | egrep -i --color 'cdrom|dvd|cd/rw|writer'
```

as

```
[   23.551700] pktcdvd: pktcdvd0: writer mapped to sr1
[   27.937232] pktcdvd: pktcdvd1: writer mapped to sr0
```

but the automount fail and don't recognize the drives , so I turn root and run manually the next command

```
mount /dev/sr1 /mnt/blank_dir
```

then the output says.

```
mount: /mnt/blank_dir: /dev/sr1 already mounted or mount point busy.
```

The `sr0` works quite well but the `sr1` don't.
I'm reviewing a huge amount of dvd so it woul be quite handy have two drives to do so.

sr1 
does not appear mounted in another point, as reported by mount

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a shell open and sitting in the /mnt/blank_dir directory?  If so, that would cause your mount point to be busy.

You can also look for links to the mount point with lsof

```
lsof /mnt/blank_dir | grep blank_dir | grep -v grep
```

to see if anything has an active link to that directory

if those are ok, try looking for errors with the drivers in the output of dmesg to see if anything odd shows up.  Something like:

```
dmesg | grep -i error
```

would probably show anything of interest

Just a few things to try.

Comment: Thanks, Im not opening the shell in the same dir, Im looking  tru the output of dmesg , also the output of lsof seems to be an error lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete